# Share files from a personal computer through a web page (with authorized access)

Tags: file, web, share

My internship tutor wants to make available, by means of a website (with authorized access), some of his porfessional files to be available for some of his coworkers?

I tried suggesting several options: FTP client, NAS device or Router with USB.
But he want to do it through a website that we are constructing right now, after of course, succesful login identification.

Is there a solution to what he wants?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Firebase's Cloud storage at https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/
You just need to create a project and include javascript code in your html page.
It also allows you to define authentication rules about who can view or add/edit files stored.